# combining salesforce and website tracking data

Tags: integration, contact, analytics

I'm using heapapp for user analytics. 
https://heapanalytics.com/

Specifically heap allows me to understand how an individual user is using my website.

I'd like to correlate this with data inside salesforce. The idea is that i'm able to understand what a user has done so that when i actively engage them i know exactly where they may be having issues and/or what steps they have completed.

Is there an easy way to merge this data inside of salesforce?

What is the recommended way to integrate website tracking data with data inside of salesforce so that i have one view?
i.e. open up salesforce -> navigate to specific contact -> see user analyticsdata.

Answer (score 0):

What is the master side data . In case if it is website then you can just upsert the records into salesforce based on some externalid .